# How to compile baremetal hello_world.c and run it on qemu-system-aarch64?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu, arm64, bare-metal

As the title, I want to compile hello_world.c program and run it on qemu-system-aarch64. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("hello world!\n");
}
```

from https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/aarch64-elf/ (this is baremetal directory), I can see these tool chains:

```
folder  aarch64-elf -       
folder  aarch64-linux-gnu   -       
folder  aarch64_be-elf  -       
folder  aarch64_be-linux-gnu    -       
folder  arm-eabi    -       
folder  arm-linux-gnueabi   -       
folder  arm-linux-gnueabihf -       
folder  armeb-eabi  -       
folder  armeb-linux-gnueabi -       
folder  armeb-linux-gnueabihf   -       
folder  armv8l-linux-gnueabihf
```

So I chose aarch64-elf (is this correct?) and installed it on my ubuntu 16.04 machine and added the bin directory to the path.
If I just do `aarch64-elf-gcc hello_world.c` I get undefined reference errors for _exit, _sbrk, _write, _close, _lseek, _read, _fstat, _isatty functions. so I tried adding -spec=aem.ve-specs and it doesn't complain (I'm not sure this is correct).
and I tried running qemu.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a57 -nographic -smp 1 -m 2048 -kernel a.out
```

and it doesn't give me any print. What should I change here?

Comment: You can compile quite easily an aarch64 linux elf binary, and then run it, but not with `qemu-system-aarch64`, instead `qemu-aarch64`. Are you sure that not this is what you want to do? My impression is that likely you want actually this.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica thanks, what I want is to use system mode. qemu-system-aarch64. we are developing an SoC these days.

Comment: Then you need a kernel, or at least some embedded lib to work. Here you have only a compiled binary, but no kernel, no libc.

Comment: can't we run baremetal program on qemu? it's an important question. I thought it should be possible. (we've run linux and rtems on qemu several years ago, but not baremtal)

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you have a `printf()` in your C code, what should it do? It should write an output to the standard output, which should be connected to some terminal hardware. This can be an emulated one, provided for you by the qemu hardware virtualization, or a real hardware (probably some LCD display). Where should be the routines which interact with this (virtual or physical) hardware? The cross compiler compiles your C code, including the `printf`, to a binary. But where should be the implementation of the printf routine?

Comment: Where is the code which translates a `call _printf` (or analogous) to hardware controlling asm? You need to provide it. It can be an OS kernel + libc (this is my suggestion). It can be some embedded framework. But something has to be there.

Comment: I thought the "-spec=aem.ve-specs" does that thing. arm toolchains provide those specs which provides hook (semihosting?) to interface with host computer's serial io and LCD during actual board test. But I'm not 100% sure if this will work on qemu. I hoped --serial stdio will again connect virtual machine's stdio to host machine's stdio.

Comment: The -spec file only says gcc where to find the libraries, which compilation flags to use, and so on. There is still nothing which would provide the system libraries and drivers.

Comment: @peterh Hi, I revisited this question and realized I didn't understand what you mean at that time. So I need all the stuff like start.S crt0.S and the linker script, . . .I stupidly thought the baremetal compiler will take care of it automatically. I've worked on baremetal program manytimes but it was after someone else had already set up the environment.

Comment: Ok, all right :-) I hope finally it went well. You can actually copy these libs (and includes) from a native aarch64 system, if you want to run them on a linux kernel. Possibly also some really baremetal thing is also possible for some microcontroll-like setup, but so you need some sdk and this sdk will give you the libs. But I think, on aarch64, and embedded linux is more common than a real baremetal.

Comment: yes, I've been running baremetal programs on qemu until last summer (sometimes these days too).  when I look back upon an old project, we had those files under lib and include and I browsed how things went at that time including printf->vsfprintf->puts->putc to the uart. I'll be looking at how semihosting works later. I'm trying to port linux on our FPGA board so looking at u-boot and it looks principally almost the same. Thank you! oh, I've a little tutorial level experience with STM32 microcontroller and had looked at the codes at that time. now I feel more like I'm a software engineer haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that you can use qemu-system-aarch64 for achieving your goal.
Depending on what you exactly want to do, you have multiple options:

1. use the [semihosting](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100863/0300/The-semihosting-interface) mode of qemu, along with the gcc `--specs=rdimon.specs` with `newlib,` or using another semihosting library, such as the one available in the Arm Trusted Firmware source code - the example hereafter uses this approach.
2. provide your own `syscalls.c` , and use the `--specs=nosys.specs` `ld` option, so that you can use newlib in baremetal programs: I would  suggest to read the excellent article from Francesco Balducci on the [Balau](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/using-newlib-in-arm-bare-metal-programs/) blog - the example hereafter uses this approach.
3. use a more baremetal-like approach, such as the one described hereafter: it does use `sprintf()` and the `pl011` UART of the `qemu-virt` machine for displaying the resulting string.

`gcc_arm64_ram.ld`:

```
/******************************************************************************
 * @file     gcc_arm32.ld
 * @brief    GNU Linker Script for Cortex-M based device
 * @version  V2.0.0
 * @date     21. May 2019
 ******************************************************************************/
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2019 Arm Limited. All rights reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the License); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an AS IS BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

MEMORY
{
  RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = __RAM_BASE, LENGTH = __RAM_SIZE
}

/* Linker script to place sections and symbol values. Should be used together
 * with other linker script that defines memory regions FLASH and RAM.
 * It references following symbols, which must be defined in code:
 *   Reset_Handler : Entry of reset handler
 *
 * It defines following symbols, which code can use without definition:
 *   __exidx_start
 *   __exidx_end
 *   __copy_table_start__
 *   __copy_table_end__
 *   __zero_table_start__
 *   __zero_table_end__
 *   __etext
 *   __data_start__
 *   __preinit_array_start
 *   __preinit_array_end
 *   __init_array_start
 *   __init_array_end
 *   __fini_array_start
 *   __fini_array_end
 *   __data_end__
 *   __bss_start__
 *   __bss_end__
 *   __end__
 *   end
 *   __HeapLimit
 *   __StackLimit
 *   __StackTop
 *   __stack
 */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

SECTIONS
{
  .text :
  {
    KEEP(*(.vectors))
    *(.text*)

    KEEP(*(.init))
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    /* .ctors */
    *crtbegin.o(.ctors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.ctors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .ctors)
    *(SORT(.ctors.*))
    *(.ctors)

    /* .dtors */
    *crtbegin.o(.dtors)
    *crtbegin?.o(.dtors)
    *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o) .dtors)
    *(SORT(.dtors.*))
    *(.dtors)

    *(.rodata*)

    KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))
  } > RAM

  /*
   * SG veneers:
   * All SG veneers are placed in the special output section .gnu.sgstubs. Its start address
   * must be set, either with the command line option �--section-start� or in a linker script,
   * to indicate where to place these veneers in memory.
   */
/*
  .gnu.sgstubs :
  {
    . = ALIGN(32);
  } > RAM
*/
  .ARM.extab :
  {
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  } > RAM

  __exidx_start = .;
  .ARM.exidx :
  {
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
  } > RAM
  __exidx_end = .;

  .copy.table :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __copy_table_start__ = .;
    LONG (__etext)
    LONG (__data_start__)
    LONG (__data_end__ - __data_start__)
    /* Add each additional data section here */
/*
    LONG (__etext2)
    LONG (__data2_start__)
    LONG (__data2_end__ - __data2_start__)
*/
    __copy_table_end__ = .;
  } > RAM

  .zero.table :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __zero_table_start__ = .;
    /* Add each additional bss section here */
/*
    LONG (__bss2_start__)
    LONG (__bss2_end__ - __bss2_start__)
*/
    __zero_table_end__ = .;
  } > RAM

  /**
   * Location counter can end up 2byte aligned with narrow Thumb code but
   * __etext is assumed by startup code to be the LMA of a section in RAM
   * which must be 4byte aligned 
   */
  __etext = ALIGN(16);

  .data : AT (__etext)
  {
    __data_start__ = .;
    *(vtable)
    *(.data)
    *(.data.*)

    . = ALIGN(16);
    /* preinit data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(16);
    /* init data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.init_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);


    . = ALIGN(16);
    /* finit data */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP(*(.fini_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);

    KEEP(*(.jcr*))
    . = ALIGN(16);
    /* All data end */
    __data_end__ = .;

  } > RAM

  /*
   * Secondary data section, optional
   *
   * Remember to add each additional data section
   * to the .copy.table above to asure proper
   * initialization during startup.
   */
/*
  __etext2 = ALIGN(16);

  .data2 : AT (__etext2)
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __data2_start__ = .;
    *(.data2)
    *(.data2.*)
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __data2_end__ = .;

  } > RAM2
*/

  .bss :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __bss_start__ = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss.*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __bss_end__ = .;
  } > RAM AT > RAM

  /*
   * Secondary bss section, optional
   *
   * Remember to add each additional bss section
   * to the .zero.table above to asure proper
   * initialization during startup.
   */
/*
  .bss2 :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __bss2_start__ = .;
    *(.bss2)
    *(.bss2.*)
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __bss2_end__ = .;
  } > RAM2 AT > RAM2
*/

  .heap (COPY) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __end__ = .;
    PROVIDE(end = .);
    . = . + __HEAP_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __HeapLimit = .;
  } > RAM

  .stack (ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM) - __STACK_SIZE) (COPY) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __StackLimit = .;
    . = . + __STACK_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(16);
    __StackTop = .;
  } > RAM
  PROVIDE(__stack = __StackTop);

  /* Check if data + heap + stack exceeds RAM limit */
  ASSERT(__StackLimit >= __HeapLimit, "region RAM overflowed with stack")
}
```

`qemu-virt-aarch64.ld`:

```
__RAM_BASE = 0x40000000;
__RAM_SIZE =  0x08000000;
__STACK_SIZE = 0x00100000;
__HEAP_SIZE  =  0x00100000;
INCLUDE gcc_arm64_ram.ld
```

`startup.s`:

```
                .title startup64.s
                .arch armv8-a
                .text
                .section .text.startup,"ax"    
                .globl Reset_Handler
Reset_Handler:
                ldr x0, =__StackTop
                mov sp, x0
                bl  main
wait:           wfe
                b wait
               .end
```

`pl011.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = ( unsigned int * ) ( uintptr_t * ) 0x9000000;

int putchar(int c)
{
    *UART0DR = c; /* Transmit char */
     return c;
}

void putchar_uart0( int c )
{
    *UART0DR = c; /* Transmit char */
}

void putc_uart0( int c )
{
    *UART0DR = c; /* Transmit char */
}

void print_uart0( const char * s )
{
    while( *s != '\0' )                     /* Loop until end of string */
    {
        *UART0DR = ( unsigned int ) ( *s ); /* Transmit char */
        s++;                                /* Next char */
    }
}

void puts_uart0( const char * s )
{
    while( *s != '\0' )                     /* Loop until end of string */
    {
        *UART0DR = ( unsigned int ) ( *s ); /* Transmit char */
        if (*s == '\n') {
           *UART0DR = ( unsigned int ) ( '\r' );
        } 
        s++;                                /* Next char */
    }
}
```

`pl011.h`:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void putchar_uart0( int c );
void print_uart0( const char * s );
void putc_uart0( int c );
void puts_uart0( const char * s );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`qemu-virt-aarch64.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "pl011.h"

// angel/semihosting interface
#define SYS_WRITE0                       0x04 
static uint64_t semihosting_call(uint32_t operation, uint64_t parameter)
{
    __asm("HLT #0xF000");
}

// syscall stubs
int _close (int fd)
{
    errno = EBADF;
    return -1;
}

int _isatty (int fd)
{
    return 1;
}

int _fstat (int fd, struct stat * st)
{
    errno = EBADF;
    return -1;
}

off_t _lseek (int fd, off_t ptr, int dir)
{
    errno = EBADF;
    return (off_t) -1;
}

int _read (int fd, void *ptr, size_t len)
{
    errno = EBADF;
    return -1;
}

int _write (int fd, const char *ptr, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        putchar_uart0(ptr[i]);
    }
    return len;
}

void main()
{
   char buffer[BUFSIZ];
   uint64_t regCurrentEL;

   __asm volatile ("mrs %0, CurrentEL" : "=r" (regCurrentEL));

   // UART0
   sprintf(buffer, "Hello EL%d World!\n", (regCurrentEL >> 2) & 0b11);
   puts_uart0(buffer);

   // angel/semihosting interface
   sprintf(buffer, "Hello semi-hosted EL%d World!\n", (regCurrentEL >> 2) & 0b11);
   semihosting_call(SYS_WRITE0, (uint64_t) (uintptr_t)  buffer);

   // newlib -  custom syscalls.c, with _write() using UART0
   printf("Hello EL%d World! (syscalls version)\n", (regCurrentEL >> 2) & 0b11);
}
```

Please note that the code responsible for initializing the `.bss` section was omitted.

Compiling:

```
/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -I. -O0 -ggdb -mtune=cortex-a53 -nostartfiles -ffreestanding --specs=nosys.specs -L. -Wl,-T,qemu-virt-aarch64.ld -o virt.elf startup.s  pl011.c qemu-virt-aarch64.c
```

Running:

```
/opt/qemu-5.2.0/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 -semihosting -m 128M -nographic  -monitor none -serial stdio  -machine virt,gic-version=2,secure=on,virtualization=on -cpu cortex-a53 -kernel virt.elf
Hello EL3 World!
Hello semi-hosted EL3 World!
Hello EL3 World! (syscalls version)
```

Comment: Wow, that's a thorough explanation! Thank you so much and I'll try this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Please do note I only have experience with x86/amd64 development. But I think some of your initial assumptions are flawed.

First of all, simply compiling C source code doesn't run bare metal by default. You use `printf`, which your compiler subsequently finds in the `stdio.h — standard buffered input/output` library. The way you compile now, this is dynamically linked to your program. That is, your program jumps into libc **during execution** when calling `printf`. You can see this with readelf.

```
readelf --dynamic a.out | grep NEEDED
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Qemu simulates the machine, but it doesn't simulate an operating system. You now pass your program, which is dynamically linked, as kernel/OS. How does your kernel know to print if there is no libc library? Even more, how does it know how to do anything since the basic booting steps are not done by your program (Setup and initialize RAM, Setup device tree, etc).

I assume you don't want to write an ARM64 kernel but just want to get into ARM64 'bare metal' development. Maybe just download an Aarch64 Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/arm64/iso-cd/debian-10.7.0-arm64-netinst.iso))?

You can create a virtual drive, install an OS, and develop in that virtual machine to get virtual 'bare metal' development ;) For example something like [this](https://futurewei-cloud.github.io/ARM-Datacenter/qemu/how-to-launch-aarch64-vm/)?

If my assumptions are wrong and you **do** want to get into OS development, that question is too long to answer here. But I would recommend looking into [tutorials](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-a-noob-guide-on-building-your-own-custom-kernel-arm-arm64-mtk.3581057/) and [documentation](https://wiki.osdev.org/ARM_Overview).

Comment: hi shoaloak, readelf --dynamic command shows 'There is no dynamic section in this file.'. so it is all statically linked.(because it's baremetal toolchain, not linux toolchain for compiling application to be run on linux). and my understanding is, if we use baremetal compiler, the basic stuff is done by the compiler(creating stack, heap, etc..) We are now developing SoC so I have to prepare qemu for our chip (very initial development stage now) and I want to verify the qemu model with baremetal program(if reg write,read is done for a fake peripheral.)