# How to run arm64 baremetal hello world program on qemu?

Tags: arm, gdb, qemu

Often a question leads me into another question.
While trying to debug an inline assembly code, I met with another basic problem.
To make long story short, I want to run arm64 baremetal hello world program on qemu.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

I compile it like this :
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -g test.c

I get undefined reference errors for `_exit` `_sbrk` `_write` `_close` `_lseek` `_read` `_fstat` and `_isatty`. I learned in the past the `-specs=rdimon.specs` compile options removes this errors.
So I ran

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -g test.c -specs=rdimon.specs
```

and it compiles ok with a.out file.
Now I run qemu baremetal program to debug the code.

> qemu-system-aarch64  -machine
> virt,gic-version=max,secure=true,virtualization=true -cpu cortex-a72
> -kernel a.out -m 2048M -nographic -s -S

and here is the gdb run result.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/testdir/testinlinedebugprint$ aarch64-none-elf-gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GNU Toolchain for the A-profile Architecture 10.2-2020.11 (arm-10.16)) 10.1.90.20201028-git
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-none-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.linaro.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) set architecture aarch64
The target architecture is set to "aarch64".
(gdb) set serial baud 115200
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
_start ()
    at /tmp/dgboter/bbs/build02--cen7x86_64/buildbot/cen7x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/libgloss/aarch64/crt0.S:90
90  /tmp/dgboter/bbs/build02--cen7x86_64/buildbot/cen7x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/libgloss/aarch64/crt0.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4002f8: file test.c, line 26.
(gdb) 
(gdb) r
The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or "continue".
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

It doesn't break and hangs.
What am I doing wrong? and how can I solve the `/tmp/dgboter/bbs/build02--cen7x86_64/buildbot/cen7x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/libgloss/aarch64/crt0.S: No such file or directory.` problem?
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

**ADD :**
I realized I have asked the same question ([How to compile baremetal hello_world.c and run it on qemu-system-aarch64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896336/how-to-compile-baremetal-hello-world-c-and-run-it-on-qemu-system-aarch64#comment124303349_65896336))  before (Ah! my memory..)  I realized I need all the stuff like start.S crt0.S and the linker script, . . .I stupidly thought the baremetal compiler will take care of it automatically when actually I have to fill the really low level things. I've worked on baremetal programs in some cases but it was after someone else had already set up those initial environment(sometimes I even modified them many times!). In baremetal, you have to privide all the things. There isn't anything you can take for granted because it's "bare metal". I realized this basic thing so late..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a program for "bare metal" that means that you need to configure your toolchain to produce a binary that works on the specific piece of bare metal that you try to run it on. For instance, the binary must:

- put its code somewhere in the machine's memory map where there is either ROM or RAM
- put its data where there is RAM
- make sure that on startup the stack pointer is correctly initialized to point into RAM
- if it wants to print output, include routines which access a suitable device on that machine. This is likely a serial port, and serial ports are often entirely different devices, located at different addresses, on different machines

If any of these things are wrong or don't match the actual machine you run on, the result is typically exactly what you see -- the program crashes without output.

More specifically, rdimon.specs tells the compiler to build in C library functions which do some of this via the "semihosting" debugger ABI (which has support for "print string" and some other things). Your QEMU command line doesn't enable implementation of semihosting (you can turn it on with the -semihosting option), so that won't work at all. But there are probably other problems you're also hitting.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I added -semihosting in qemu option and connected gdb. The $pc value starts from 0x400178 <_start> but it generates exception and $pc stays in 0x200 which is `synchronous exception, current EL with SPx`. Can you suggest me what I can do further? I can't find the crt0.S file used in the toolchain and can't see it.

Comment: I realized the program starts at 0x400000 but that region is flash memory in arm 'virt' machine. so I extracted the default linker script (using -Wl,--verbose during ld command) and tried chaning the program entry to 0x80000000 (DRAM). but it gives me : aarch64-none-elf-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400000. I'll try later. maybe I have to provide flash image with the program.. like once I did months ago.

Comment: Ah! I realized what you mean and updated my question. I had asked the same question before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896336/how-to-compile-baremetal-hello-world-c-and-run-it-on-qemu-system-aarch64#comment124303349_65896336